# constructor initialization lists order/allocation question

Tags: c++, constructor

My question is simple, is the next code safe?

```
struct Parent {
    B* _a;
    Parent(B* a) : _a(a) {}
};

struct Child : public Parent {
    B _b;
    Child() : Parent(&_b),  _b(2){};
};

int main() {
    Child c;
    return 0;
}
```

Two more points:

- I am interested in the part of passing a reference to a member object to the parent.
- By safe I mean that `_b` will be allocated (and its memory address) and that this code will work regardless of which compiler I use.

Thanks in advance.

**clarification**
by safe I actually meant that the memory address was valid, since I already knew It was not initialized.

**other notes**
In my actual code I wanted to store the object of type `B` as a pointer to its base class `A`, like this:

```
struct Parent {
    A* _a;
    Parent(A* a) : _a(a) {}
};

struct Child : public Parent {
    B _b;
    Child() : Parent(&_b),  _b(2){};
};

int main() {
    Child c;
    return 0;
}
```

Which, if I understand AndreyT answer correctly, is illegal. I guess I'll try to do this differently, since this approach was error prone. (I might forget that I couldn't use that pointer and do something with it in my next refactor).

Comment: what are A and B? Because you're initializing a B* member with A*. Does A derives B ? Also, does B has constructor, that takes `int` or something ?

Comment: Presumably the `Parent` constructor should be `Parent(B *a)`?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov typo, in my initial example A was a superclass of B. That was to show why I would need it.

Comment: @João Portela - Okay, please refer to James McNellis' or AndreyT answer (:

Comment: @João Portela: Note that if `A` was a superclass of `B`, and you were actually trying to store a pointer to `A`, your code would be illegal (see my answer for details)

Comment: thx for the great answers. I ended up choosing AndreyT answer because he even answered something I wanted to know but wasn't asking ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the sense that you describe, yes it is safe: the memory is allocated and it is perfectly fine to pass that pointer to the parent. The memory for `Child::_b` is actually integral part of the memory of the entire `Child`. It doesn't require any explicit additional "allocations". By the moment the `Child::Child` constructor is invoked, the memory is obviously already there.

However, the memory the pointer points to can only be used in number of limited ways (the standard describes in 3.8 what can and what cannot be done with it), since the object it points to has not been initialized yet. In your specific example you simply store the pointer. That is perfectly OK.

But if you, for example, wanted to convert that pointer to some base class type (assuming for a second that `B` has some base class), you code would be illegal. It is illegal to convert pointers to uninitialized objects to their base class pointers (again, see 3.8).

Answer (score 6):

The order of initialization is as follows:

```
// Base classes:
Parent(&_b)

// Members:
_b(2)

// Constructor Body:
Child() { }
```

Whether this is safe depends on your definition of "safe."  By your definition ("will it work?"), yes, it is safe.  The lifetime of `Child::_b` begins when the `Child` object is created, so you can obtain a pointer to it and that pointer refers to an object.  However, you can't use the pointed-to value until after `_b` is initialized, which is after the constructor of the base class, `Parent`, has returned.

Answer (score 1):

The parent constructor will be called first and you will be passing the address of an unitiliazed member variable to that constructor.  It's not safe.

edit:

I think AndreyT stated more clearly and more vividly the type of problems that sprang to mind when I wrote my answer.  Those are the types of errors that aren't immediately perceivable.  The kind that will keep you up at night attempting to figure out where the dangling pointer exists in your code or where the memory corruption is occurring.

Comment: Won't this work (if not ideal design) so long as base class does not use the derived class member in its construction?

Comment: That was my immediate thought; but are you sure it's unsafe (as in "undefined) merely to pass the *address* of an uninitialised variable?

Comment: I would say it's unsafe in a sense that later somebody might be tempted to use the pointer in `A`'s constructor. It is not obvious from `A`'s code why this is not legal. Leaving such trapdoors in one's code is unsafe.

Comment: @Alex Emelianov: This is indeed a reasonable definition of "unsafe".